# Why no FullGC but old gen from 99% to 14% display in results of the jstat -gcutil?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

jstat -gcutil as shown below:

[image]

The old gen first from 13.78 to 99.98,then to 14.81,but the FGCT is always 1,
Why?

In addition to FullGC, there are other reasons to cause this situation?

**GC is CMS and JVM parameters:**

> -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=32 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=8 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenPrecleaningEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection

Comment: Which JVM version are you on?

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 24.55-b03

Comment: Can you reproduce this? If so, please provide the output from jstat -gc (not -gcutil) as well. Running the JVM with -XX:+PrintGCDetails provides additional detail, such a log file could also help.

Comment: this occurred in my production environment,difficult to reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A HotSpot JVM full GC is counted when **the young generation and the permanent generation** are collected... (Source: [Analyzing the Performance Impact of Memory Utilization and Garbage Collection](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/analyzing-java-memory.aspx),  goto section Major vs. Minor Garbage Collections)
2. There is a **ambigious use out there of the term "full garbage collection" in different tools**, some show no GC events and others report gc events if run at the same time and the same JVM. *Keep this in mind if you have to compare output/reports.*

So back to your question:

When I take a look at your output I can see that the permantent space utilization is increasing. It started with 19.59 and is 19.70 in the last line of your output.  **No permanent generation GC occured until that moment**. That is the reason why FGC is still 1.

Additional some notes regarding the jstats -gcutil output.

- O: Old space utilization, or as you call it old gen.
- P: Permanent space utilization
- YGC: young generation garbage collection count
- FGC: full garbage collection count
- GCT: Total garbage collection time.

`.  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC    YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 12.44   0.00  27.20   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672
 12.44   0.00  62.16   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672
 12.44   0.00  83.97   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672
  0.00   7.74   0.00   9.51  96.70    79    0.177     5    0.495    0.673`

The shown values for YGC, YGCT, FGC and FGCT *refer to the moment the Hotspot JVM started* and no to the moment when you started jstat -gcutil. Just the case you are wondering the output might start with e.g. 12 FGC in the first line.

Here is the jstat doc: [Java 6 jstat doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html#gcutil_option)

Comment: I do not think this answer is correct. I am running some tests with the same JVM parameters and I get an increase in FGC count even though my perm gen is not collected. That is my experience from our own applications as well. FGC when viewed from jstat increases with CMS old gen collections.

Comment: But in the image above FGC does not increase when the old gen is colected, thats strange... I also could not find any information about the source of the FGC number. Does anybody know from where this value is read?

Answer (score 2):

I did some tests on my own and my conclusion is that it seems to be a bug in jstat when running with your JVM parameters. I ran jstat -gc and jstat -gcutil at the same time on a simple test application and I had the following output:

jstat -gc:

```
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU
29120,0 29120,0  0,0    0,0   466048,0 18642,2  3670016,0     0,0
29120,0 29120,0  0,0    0,0   466048,0 18642,2  3670016,0     0,0
29120,0 29120,0  0,0    0,0   466048,0 18642,2  3670016,0     0,0
29120,0 29120,0  0,0    0,0   466048,0 18642,2  3670016,0     0,0
29120,0 29120,0  0,0    0,0   466048,0 18642,2  3670016,0     0,0
29120,0 29120,0  0,0    0,0   466048,0 55926,2  3670016,0     0,0
29120,0 29120,0  0,0    0,0   466048,0 369663,6 3670016,0     0,0
29120,0 29120,0  0,0   29120,0 466048,0 466048,0 3670016,0   94773,6
29120,0 29120,0  0,0   29120,0 466048,0 299100,8 3670016,0   118478,6
29120,0 29120,0 29120,0  0,0   466048,0  9163,2  3670016,0   254498,6
```

jstat -gcutil

```
 S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  0,00   0,00   4,00   0,00   0,93      0    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00   0,00   4,00   0,00   0,93      0    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00   0,00   4,00   0,00   0,93      0    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00   0,00   4,00   0,00   0,93      0    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00   0,00   4,00   0,00   0,93      0    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00   0,00  26,00   0,00   0,97      0    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00   0,00  89,32   0,00   0,97      0    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00 100,00 100,00 100,00   0,97      1    0,000     0    0,000    0,000
  0,00 100,00  80,02   3,23   0,97      1    0,905     0    0,000    0,905
100,00   0,00  13,76   6,93   0,97      2    1,441     0    0,000    1,441
```

As you can see, my Old used when running -gcutil jumps to 100 even though the application just started filling old gen. jstat -gc shows the old generation almost entirely empty. The application is very simple and just fills up a HashMap, why there is no way that old gen would be 100% full when jstat -gcutil says so.

Comment: thx.I think maybe it's is not a bug,just not very accurate when used CMS.